How to represent scons dependency on an optional file?
TL;DR, how to add scons dependency on an optional file which may or may not exist?
Let's say that we have an scons builder like the one below where the command processor reads an optional config file .processorrc which configures its operation.
I understand how to add a dependency on a file that exists or can be created automatically but how can I represent a dependency on the optional file .processorrc such that any change/deletion/creation of ti will cause processor to be executed?
bld = Builder(action = 'processor < $SOURCE > $TARGET')


You probably need an Emitter.

Does anything in the sources for this builder indicate that there will be a .processorrc? or processorrc just always looks to see if it's present and uses it if is?

@bdbaddog, there is no indication in the source files. The processor job use the rc file if it finds it or use default configuration if not, and the configuration in effect changes the output files that the processor generates.

Ok and this  .processorrc is not generated by any SCons logic, but rather is just on the system or not?  Can this file be located in more than one directory? for example ~/.processorrc or /.processorrc, or only in the directory it's run in?

Don't promise you can get this to work in a way that suits your needs, but you might be able to rig something up with ParseDepends. That method reads an external dependency file to add dependency relationships, and by default just skips it if the dep file isn't there. However, it would be an additional file you have to create if the dot file you want to optionally depend on exists, because the dep file itself has to be in a specific format (target: dep1 dep2... depN). See if this gives you any ideas:
https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#id1330
(sorry that's one of the User Guide chapters that hasn't yet been converted to named section anchors, so it's kind of a funky link).
Edited:  here's a very simple-minded example of this in play, with stuff hardcoded, etc.:
import pathlib

DOTFILEPATH = ".fuggle"
DEPFILEPATH = "fuggle.dep"

def dot_dep(source, target, env) -> None:
    """Manage dependency file based on existence of DOTFILEPATH."""    
    dotfile = pathlib.Path(DOTFILEPATH)
    depfile = pathlib.Path(DEPFILEPATH)
    if dotfile.exists():
        if not depfile.exists():
            deptext = f"foo: {DOTFILEPATH}\n"
            depfile.write_text(deptext)
    else:
        depfile.unlink(missing_ok=True)

Execute(dot_dep)
ParseDepends(DEPFILEPATH)

Command("foo", "foo.in", Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))

Here's the file being removed in action:
$ scons -Q --tree=all --debug=explain
dot_dep([], [])
scons: `.' is up to date.
+-.
  +-.fuggle
  +-SConstruct
  +-foo
  | +-foo.in
  | +-.fuggle
  +-foo.in
$ rm .fuggle
$ scons -Q --tree=all --debug=explain
dot_dep([], [])
scons: rebuilding `foo' because `.fuggle' is no longer a dependency
Copy("foo", "foo.in")
+-.
  +-.fuggle
  +-SConstruct
  +-foo
  | +-foo.in
  +-foo.in


I think that this is similar to what I am doing now, if the file .processorrc exists I add it as a dependency of the source file. I am not sure however that this is guaranteed to work correctly, for example if .processorrc is deleted and the dependency is removed, is scons guaranteed to rebuild next time?

Yes that should work, if the dep chain for a target changes, SCons always rebuilds. I have to paste the snip of my toy example doing that in another answer, since I can't put a code block in a comment.
